# angular.js:13920 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $uibModalInstanceProvider <- $uibModalInstance <- empCtrl

Tags: angularjs

I am using a ui-bootstrap modal to submit a form, my modal is loading fine but my "Cancel" button doesn't work properly and i am getting the above mentioned error message.

my app.js

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);

myApp.controller('empCtrl', [
    '$scope', '$http', '$uibModal', '$uibModalInstance', function ($scope, $http, $uibModal, $uibModalInstance) {


        $scope.employees = "";


        $http.get("/Home/GetEmployees").success(function(result) {
            $scope.employees = result;
        }).error(function(result) {
            alert("error");
        });


        $scope.saveData = function(employee) {
            $http.post("/Home/AddEmployee", { employee: employee }).sucess(function(result) {
                alert(result);

            }).error(function(result) {
                alert(result);
            });
        }

        $scope.showCreateEmployeeForm = function() {
            $uibModal.open(
            {
                templateUrl: "app/employeeTemplate/employeeAdd.html",
                controller: 'empCtrl'

            });

            $uibModalInstance.cancel();


        }

        $scope.cancelForm= function() {
            $uibModalInstance.dismiss();
        }


    }
]);
```

my modal in html

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="empCtrl">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h1>Create Employee</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-lg-4 input-group">
                <label>Name</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <input type="text" ng-model="employee.name" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-lg-4 input-group">
                <label>Address</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <input type="text" ng-model="employee.address" />
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-9" >
            <input type="submit" value="Save" name="Save" ng-click="saveData(employee)" />
            <input type="submit" value="Cancel" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="cancelForm()" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

can someone please help me to figure out what's going on with my code.
Cheers!!!

Comment: Can you please just do this : 
myApp.controller('empCtrl',  function ($scope, $http, $uibModal, $uibModalInstance)

Comment: @BeslindaN. I am still getting the same error, I have tried everything but still coudn't found the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is something weird on the controller. For the modal and for place where you init the modal you use the same controller. Your code should be in this format:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);

myApp.controller('empCtrl', [
    '$scope', '$http', '$uibModal', function ($scope, $http, $uibModal) {

    $scope.employees = "";

    $http.get("/Home/GetEmployees").success(function(result) {
        $scope.employees = result;
    }).error(function(result) {
        alert("error");
    });

    $scope.showCreateEmployeeForm = function() {
        $uibModal.open(
        {
            templateUrl: "app/employeeTemplate/employeeAdd.html",
            controller: function($scope, $http, $uibModalInstance){
              $scope.saveData = function(employee) {
                  $http.post("/Home/AddEmployee", { employee: employee }).sucess(function(result) {
                      alert(result);

                  }).error(function(result) {
                      alert(result);
                  });
              }
              $scope.cancelForm= function() {
                  $uibModalInstance.dismiss();
              }
            }
            resolve: {
              return $scope.employees;
            }
        });
    }
}
]);
```

Comment: No prb. I am glad I helped